# What is `weight_decay` meta parameter in Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

Looking at an example [`'solver.prototxt'`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/tutorial/examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_solver.prototxt#L15), posted on BVLC/caffe git, there is a training meta parameter

```
weight_decay: 0.04
```

What does this meta parameter mean? And what value should I assign to it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `weight_decay` meta parameter govern the regularization term of the neural net.

During training a regularization term is added to the network's loss to compute the backprop gradient. The `weight_decay` value determines how dominant this regularization term will be in the gradient computation.

As a rule of thumb, the more training examples you have, the weaker this term should be. The more parameters you have (i.e., deeper net, larger filters, larger InnerProduct layers etc.) the higher this term should be.

Caffe also allows you to choose between `L2` regularization (default) and `L1` regularization, by setting

```
regularization_type: "L1"
```

However, since in most cases weights are small numbers (i.e., `-1<w<1`), the `L2` norm of the weights is significantly smaller than their `L1` norm. Thus, if you choose to use `regularization_type: "L1"` you might need to tune `weight_decay` to a significantly smaller value.

While learning rate may (and usually does) change during training, the regularization weight is fixed throughout.

Comment: Maybe you could explain the reasons behind your rule of thumb? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Janosch usually one needs to use regularization when there are more parameters than constraints on a numerical problem. In learning, training examples represents "constraints". So, if you have (much) more training examples than free parameters, you need to worry less about overfitting and you can reduce the regularization term. However, if you have very few training examples (compared to the number of parameters) then your model is prone to overfitting and you need strong regularization term to prevent this from happening

Comment: Do you have to set `param { lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 1 }` in the `convolution` layer or is the regularization type global? @Shai

Comment: the global `weight_decay` multiplies the parameter-specific `decay_mult`. @thigi

Comment: That means when the parameter is `unset` or `zero` this does not have any influence? Which one is the default `regularization` ? And which one would you preferably use? My problem is overfitting -> train loss lower than test loss @Shai

Answer (score 16):

Weight decay is a regularization term that penalizes big weights.
When the weight decay coefficient is big the penalty for big weights is also big, when it is small weights can freely grow.

Look at this answer (not specific to caffe) for a better explanation:
[Difference between neural net *"weight decay"* and *"learning rate"*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29130/difference-between-neural-net-weight-decay-and-learning-rate).

Comment: I know it's a long time since you posted this, but what is the pros and cons of freely grown weights?