# Navigating hyper-parameters

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I was just wondering if someone could provide a good source for me to read on how I should approach choosing hyper-parameters of the solver based on the complexity of my problem.

Basically, I understand that many feel that they are "shooting around in the dark" when it comes to setting and then modifying these parameters and a system or benchmark for choosing parameters based on specific problem/data complexity has escaped me.

If you care to explain your own methodology or simply provide commentary on your source, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: One of these "hyper-parameters" is `'weight_decay'`. You can find a thread discussing its role and some "rule of thumb" to setting its value [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32177764/1714410).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the hyperparameters we're talking about are related to **backpropagation**, which is a gradient-based approach, I believe the main reference is [Y. Bengio](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533), along with the more classic [Lecun et al.](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf).

There are three main approaches to find out the optimal value for an hyperparameter. The first two are well explained in the first paper I linked.

- Manual search. The researcher choose the optimal value through try-and-error.
- Automatic search. The researcher relies on an automated routine in order to speed up the search.
- Bayesian Optimization. You can find a video presenting it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VG2uCpKJkSg).

Comment: The video was great! Great theory. I'll try and keep up to date with Bengio; so glad that the theory of machine learning is being researched and codified.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the main reference:

http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf

Also take a look at Chapter 5 in:
http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/

Comment: The paper from Krizhevsky et al. is just an example of choosing (good) hyperparameters. It doesn't provide a methodology or a theorical foundation for their choice, e.g., batch size, learning rate or weight decay.

Comment: If there were a theoretical foundation it would be much easier! As far as I can tell it is all try and error or computer aided trial and error.

Comment: Indeed. Stay tuned on Yoshua Bengio's work, his lab is working hard on deep learning theory.