# how to implement L2 Regularization in caffe or DIGITS?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am using Caffe and also NVIDIA DIGITS. I want to use AlexNet pretrained on ImageNet and wanna fine tune it on my medical data. I have nearly 1000 images and using 80% for training, I generated 40,000 images by data augmentation (using cropping and rotation). However I face a severe overfitting. I tried to overcome this by adding multiple dropout layers. and the result change from :

[image: results 1]

to:

[image: results 2]

but my accuracy does not improve.

my network specifications:

`AlexNet pre-trained on ImageNet`

`base learning rate: 0.001`

`learning rate multiplier: 0.1 for convolution layers and 1 for fully connected layers and xavier weight initialisation.`

`dropout: 0.5`

Now I want to add L2 regularization. I did not find such layer in Caffe and I should maybe make it myself.

`first question:` Do you have any solution for my problem? ( I have tried other ways like changing stepsize, changing learning rate from `1` to `10^(-5)` and I found `0.001` is better, weigh decay changes, adding various dropout layer (which helped as you see))

`second question:` can you please help me how I can implement L2 regularization??

Answer (score 1):

You have `L2` regularization by default in caffe.
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32177764/1714410) for more information.